# ftp Clients doesn't seem to work under proxy

Tags: proxy, ftp

My office computers are proxied and `filezilla` doesn't seem to work for me.

So I looked for a Firefox addon `FireFTP` and that too did not work either witht the proxy.

Any ways to use a FTP client on a host which is behind a proxy?

Comment: Are you using filezilla in passive mode? If that doesn't work, I think you're SOL. Normal FTP needs to be able to accept an incoming connection for transfering data (e.g, the server opens a connection to your computer, not vice versa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two kinds of proxy for FTP.

The first is a native FTP proxy. This is very rare in my experience. The FTP proxy provides proxy network access at the FTP command level. If you are using this environment, then the FTP mode might matter.

The second is proxy of FTP over HTTP. A good way to think about it is to understand that browsers "HTTP" proxy is really a URL proxy over HTTP. So, in the case of ftp, the FTP URL is sent to the HTTP proxy over HTTP, and the file is returned inside an HTTP proxy response to the browser (which still transparently treats the data as an FTP transfer). In this environment, there is no proxy client (browser) FTP transfer mode, it delegates the request to the FTP module of the HTTP proxy.